# Find all records within x units of each other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t(idx integer primary key, value integer);
INSERT INTO t(idx, value)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 6),
    (5, 7),
    (6, 12)
```

I would like to return all the groups of records where the values are within 2 of each other, with an associated group label as a new column by which to identify them.

I thought perhaps a recursive query might be suitable...but my sql-fu is lacking.

Comment: share your output

Comment: Would the `value` always be increasing as `idx` also increases?

Comment: yes, the values increase

Comment: What you mean by "within 2 of each other?". That any two values in each group may differ only by at most 2? Or simple pairwise grouping by 2 rows?

Comment: this - "That any two values in each group may differ only by at most 2"

Comment: What if you had 1/2/3/4?  Would this be one group or two?

Comment: This would be two groups in my simple model. The value column is actually the timestamp of a search. I am trying to pick out groups of related searches using an arbitrary window of say, 5min. I think a better model would treat 1/2/3/4 as one group. I am trying to figure out the efficacy of an internal search engine, by tracking the average number of search attempts per "unique" search. I do not have access to the search term used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive tt as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by idx) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select idx, value, value as grp,
             seqnum, 1 as lev
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.idx, tt.value, 
             (case when tt.value > grp + 2 then tt.value else cte.grp end),
             tt.seqnum, 1 + lev
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bcdfa213d4142d7c2009a34ac3901a55) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that this added a row with the value of "4" to show that the first four rows are split into two groups.

Comment: (line 2) - What is the purpose of `row_number() over (order by idx) as seqnum` ? If the purpose is to create an index on increasing value, shouldn't `idx` be `value`?

Comment: @GlaceCelery . . . I interpreted the question as "going through the rows in order by `idx`, then when is the value condition met".  In your sample data, both the `id` and `value` are increasing, so it doesn't make a difference which is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to group rows so that any two values in each group may differ only by at most 2. Then you are right, recursive query is the solution. In each level of recursion the bounds of new group are precomputed. Groups are disjoint so finally join original table with computed group number and group by this number. [Db fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6d24e73e025eceb8aa090dce2ffc7e33)

```sql
with recursive r (minv,maxv,level) as (
  select min(t.value), min(t.value) + 2, 1
  from t
  union all
  select minv, maxv, level from (
    select t.value as minv, t.value + 2 as maxv, r.level + 1 as level, row_number() over (order by minv) rn
    from r
    join t on t.value > r.maxv
  ) x where x.rn = 1
)
select r.level
     , format('ids from %s to %s', min(t.idx), max(t.idx)) as id_label
     , format('values from %s to %s', min(t.value), max(t.value)) as value_label
from t join r on t.value between r.minv and r.maxv
group by r.level
order by r.level
```

(The inner query in the recursive part is just to limit number of newly added rows only to one. Simpler clause `select min(t.value), min(t.value) + 2` is not possible because aggregation functions are not allowed in recursive part, analytic function is workaround.)

Comment: Great - is it possible to present the output in long format?

Comment: What you mean by long format? Please show example what you expect.

Comment: see Gordon's soln - the "grp" column